# How to pass userId to headers in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, http-headers

I'm trying to pass the userId to the headers in this call:

> api.service.ts

```
onUpdateJamItMessageBoard( dispMsg: any, dispStartTs: any, dispEndTs: any, userId: any) {
    const url = this.updateJamItMessageBoard + 'messages';
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('dispMsg', String(dispMsg))
      .set('dispStartTs', String(dispStartTs))
      .set('dispEndTs', String(dispEndTs));
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'userId': String (userId)
      });


return this.http.post<JamIt>(url, null, {
  params: params, headers: headers
  });
}
```

I'm subscribing to it here:

> jamit.component.ts

```
onUpdateJamIt() {
    let dispMsg = this.jamItMessageForMessageCenter + ' ' + this.jamItMessage + ' ' + this.freeText;
    let dispStartTs = this.startTimer;
    let dispEndTs = this.endTimer;
    let userId = '';

    this.apiEndPointService.onUpdateJamItMessageBoard(dispMsg.trim(), dispStartTs.trim(), dispEndTs.trim(), userId.trim()).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
    });

  }
```

and here's where I use it in the HTML:

> jamit.component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onUpdateJamIt()">Update</button>
```

When I click on the click event, I pass all the other parameters except the UserId and I don't know why. Please help. Am I doing it wrong? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is `userId`? You are simply sending a harcoded empty string.

Comment: @AmitChigadani `userId` as coming as params

Comment: @AmitChigadani yeah, im sending a string to test it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('userId', userId);
```

For more information check out here -

- https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-httpclient-get-example#parameters